# Need a DATE related excel function (i think)

Tags: excel

I have a report that lists by column the following:

- Column A: Client Name
- Column B: Number of payments remaining
- Column C: Amount of each Payment
- Column D: Frequency of Payments (Weekly, Every Other Week, Twice a Month, Monthly)
- Column E: Date of next payment, formatted MM/DD/YYYY

I need to extrapolate the dates of the upcoming invoices.

I have reviewed the various DATE and EDATE functions, but I am not finding one that seems like it will do what I need. I am still pretty green with excel functions and haven't quite learned how to ask the right questions. I have googled a few different queries, but none of them are returning remotely the correct answer. Hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You would need a date of the last invoice.  Or at least a starting date.  Then you can simply add the number of days based on the frequency

Comment: Isn't "every other week" the same as "twice a month"?

Comment: @SolarMike 1st and 15th versus every 14 days is not the same.